# Query in sql on db2 database

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using this query:

```
select substr("Message_Time",6,2) || '/' || substr("Message_Time",4,2) || '/' || '20'|| substr("Message_Time",2,2) || substr("Message_Time",8,2) || ':' || substr("Message_Time",10,2) as "Date",
       count(*) as "Fault", "Message_Location", "Service_Name_U", "Operation_Name_U", "Port_Namespace_U", 
      "Error_Code_U", "Error_SubCode_U", "Fault_Code_U", "Fault_String_U",
       "Requester_Identity", "Application_ServerName_U"
from "Fault_Log_Table_610"
where "Message_Time" >= 1181016220000000 and "Message_Time" < 1181017220000000 and
      "Operation_Name_U" = 'getDomandeDisabile'
group by substr("Message_Time", 6, 2) || '/' || substr("Message_Time", 4, 2)  || '/' || '20'|| substr("Message_Time", 2, 2) || substr("Message_Time",8,2) || ':' || substr("Message_Time",10,2), 
       "Service_Name_U", "Operation_Name_U", "Error_Code_U", "Error_SubCode_U", "Message_Location", "Fault_Code_U", "Fault_String_U",
       "Port_Namespace_U", "Requester_Identity", "Application_ServerName_U"
```

I need to add 2 hours to Date field, in other words I need to add the number 2 to substr("Message_Time",8,2).

The date has the format 1181020164532000 where:

first number is century
then following two numbers are the years
then following two numbers are the months
then following two numbers are the days
then following two numbers are the hours
then following two numbers are the minutes
and last three numbers are milliseconds

Comment: Store timestamps as `TIMESTAMP` values. Don't use `VARCHAR`. You'll run into a lot of issues if you use `VARCHAR`.

Comment: So it would decompose as: 1-18-10-20-16-45-32-000? Century `1`?

Answer (score 1):

I would pre-compute the timestamp parsing and then add the 2 hours in a CTE (Common Table Expression).

Then I would use this ready-to-use data in the query you want. Something like:

```
with x as (
select
    timestampadd(8, 2, -- add 2 hours
      timestamp_format( -- parse the VARCHAR into a TIMESTAMP
                       '20' || substr("Message_Time",2,15) || '000',
                       'YYYYMMDDHHMISSNNNNNN')
    ) as "Date",
    "Message_Location", "Service_Name_U", 
    "Operation_Name_U", "Port_Namespace_U", 
    "Error_Code_U", "Error_SubCode_U", "Fault_Code_U", "Fault_String_U",
    "Requester_Identity", "Application_ServerName_U"
from "Fault_Log_Table_610"
where "Message_Time" >= 1181016220000000
  and "Message_Time" < 1181017220000000
  and "Operation_Name_U" = 'getDomandeDisabile'
)
select
    "Date",
    count(*) as "Fault",
    "Message_Location", "Service_Name_U", 
    "Operation_Name_U", "Port_Namespace_U", 
    "Error_Code_U", "Error_SubCode_U", "Fault_Code_U", "Fault_String_U",
    "Requester_Identity", "Application_ServerName_U"
from x
group by "Date", 
    "Service_Name_U", "Operation_Name_U", "Error_Code_U", "Error_SubCode_U",
    "Message_Location", "Fault_Code_U", "Fault_String_U",
    "Port_Namespace_U", "Requester_Identity", "Application_ServerName_U"
```

Comment: or create a VIEW over the table that does the conversion to timestamp if it too much effort to change the column to TIMESTAMP in the first place. You could even make it generated column, or a functional index to help query performance

Comment: @PaulVernon I agree. A generated column (persisted) would work quite well for this kind of situation.